# nginx vhost, problem service .css as static file or dynamic file

Tags: nginx

I have problems matching my requirements:
I want 2 things;

1. `https://www.test-boutique.vm/store.css` to be routed to the PHP application because the file content is streamed by the app;
2. `https://www.test-boutique.vm/static/css/basic.css` to be served from the filesystem because it exists on it;

My vhost is :

```
server {
    listen 443;

    server_name www.test-boutique.vm;

    root /srv/app/public/front;
    index index.php;


    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # css are for the files generated by the application (store.css)
    location ~ \.(php|htm|css)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.app.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|ico)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        expires 7d;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        add_header Cache-Control must-revalidate;
    }

   rewrite ^/media/(.*)$ https://test.cloud/$http_host/media/$1 permanent;
   rewrite ^/img/(.*)$ https://test.cloud/$http_host/img/$1 permanent;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/fov4_access_log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/fov4_error_log;
}
```

With this version:

1. ✅ `/store.css` file works well (generated by the PHP application)
2. ❌ `/static/css/basic.css` is trying to be served by the PHP application instead of serving the file directly from the filesystem (the file exists for sure under this path)

When removing the `css` part from the vhost 
(`location ~ \.(php|htm|css)$ {` **TO NEW** `location ~ \.(php|htm)$ {`

1. ❌ `/store.css` file is trying to be served as a static asset and ends up 404 (the request is not passed to the application)
2. ✅ `/static/css/basic.css` is served correctly

What am I missing please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching all css files like you do here: `location ~ \.(php|htm|css)$ {`, try matching that one css file that you need to have generated by PHP:

```
location ~ \.(php|htm)$ {
  # you php-fpm config here
}

location ~* \.(js|css|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|ico)$ {
   # your static files config here
}

location = /store.css {
   # you php-fpm config here
}
```

Comment: It works well, but as soon as you add: `/store.css?version=12.0.2` it returns a 404.

Comment: you can use a regexp for store.css then also